# Vector Spaces and Rank

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$. Suppose $W$ is a subspace of $L(V,V)$ so that $ST,TS\in W$ $\forall S\in L(V,V)$ and $\forall T\in W$.

Suppose $\exists T\in W:\operatorname{rank}T\neq0$.

Show that $\exists T'\in W:\operatorname{rank}T'=1$.

General observations: If $T$ is the map such that its rank is $>0$, then clearly $T$ is not the zero map. So what I need to find is a linear map $T'$ such that $\dim(\operatorname{Ker}T')=n-1$. If $\operatorname{rank}T=1$, then we are done, so I can suppose that $\operatorname{rank}T>1$.

Let $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ be a basis for $V$. Let $T$ be the linear map with non-zero rank. That means there exists a non-zero vector $w_j$ that is part of a basis for $\operatorname{im}T\subseteq V$. Therefore, defining a linear map $T':V\to V$ by $T(v_i)=w_j$ for each $i$, yields a unique linear map such that $\operatorname{im}T'=\operatorname{span}(w_j)$. This implies that $\dim(\operatorname{im}T')=1$. Hence it suffices to show that $T'$ is in $W$. I'm not sure how to show that it is in $W$. May someone help?

If I'm on the wrong path, I'd like help on getting on the right path.

Comment: What does this have to do with $\sin z$?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork oops! I forgot to change the title.

Comment: What does the body of your question have to do with $\sin z$ holomorphic?

Comment: @MichaelBurr You are right. I misread.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is that

> there exists a non-zero vector $w_j$ that is part of the basis for $\operatorname{im}T\subseteq V$.

Then you can let $S$ be a projection onto the one-dimensional $\operatorname{span}(w_j)$, and $T'=ST\in W$ is what you want.